# Laravel 5: Access database data from within model

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to use Laravel to access some data from the database. I have setup my model, which works fine, however I'm trying to fetch some data from another table by creating a method within the model which fetches the data and sets a property of the model equal to the fetched data.

To fetch the data, I'm trying to use the `$this->id` property to fetch this row's ID and use it to fetch data from another table (eg: `SomeOtherModel::where('other_id', '=', $this->id)->get();`)

However, none of the data from the database seems to have been fetched by the model at this point (eg: `$this->id` is null). My constructor looks like so:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->other_data = $this->getOtherData();
}
```

Is there any way to call the `$this->id` property from the database so I can use it within the model itself?

Comment: I would recommend using [Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships).

Comment: You probably are trying to use `Active Record` Eloquent in a way, that collides with its features, instead of making use of it. Anyway, in the constructor there is obviously no attribute set yet, so you can't do that there.  Read this http://xyproblem.info/ and rephrase your question, so maybe we can help you out

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seemed to me wrong:

```
SomeOtherModel::where('other_id', '=', $this->id)->get();
```

Can you try this:

```
SomeOtherModel::where('other_id', $this->id)->get();
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

I hope this helps .

Comment: His syntax is correct. Both lines of code in your answer are valid and should work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317398/laravel-eager-loading-a-method-not-a-relationship-of-an-eloquent-model):

```
class ExampleModel extends Model {
  protected $appends = ['otherdata'];

  public function getOtherdataAttribute() {
    return $this->getOtherData();
  }
}
```