# Laravel - eager loading a method (not a relationship) of an Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Like we can eager load a relationship of an Eloquent model, is there any way to eager load a method which is not a relationship method of the Eloquent model?

For example, I have an Eloquent model `GradeReport` and it has the following method:

```
public function totalScore()
{
    return $scores = DB::table('grade_report_scores')->where('grade_report_id', $this->id)->sum('score');
}
```

Now I am getting a collection of `GradeReport` Eloquent models.

```
$gradeReports = GradeReport::where('student_id', $studentId)->get();
```

How can I eager load the returning values of `totalScore` method for all `GradeReport` Eloquent models in the collection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add arbitrary properties to your models by adding them to **$appends** array and providing a getter. In your case the following should do the trick:

```
class GradeReport extends Model {
  protected $appends = ['totalScore'];

  public function getTotalScoreAttribute() {
    return $scores = DB::table('grade_report_scores')->where('grade_report_id', $this->id)->sum('score');
  }
}
```

Now all GradeReport objects returned from your controllers will have totalScore attribute set.

Comment: it might solve the problem, but it is not eager loading, every time this model attribute is accessed, an call to DB is made

Comment: This works as I have intended. However, I would like to have a small change for the attribute to look better. `protected $appends = ['total_score'];`.

Comment: @animaacija It might not be eager loaded, but it works as I needed. I guess it's not possible to eager load in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The table `grade_report_scores` would also have an eloquent model **xyz** on which you define a relationship, query scopes, functions, etc.

Add relationship into GradeReport model:

```
public function scores()
{
    return $this->hasMany('xyz', 'grade_report_id', 'id');
}
```

Now you can rewrite your `totalScore` function into this:

```
public function totalScores()
{
    return $this->with(['scores' => function ($query) {
        $query->sum('score');
    }])->get();
}
```

*not tested, note the closure, there bight be a need to call `$query->select('id', 'srore', 'other used values');`*